# How can we read historical data using databricks from kinesis or kafka by specifying starting and ending time stamp?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Lets says I'd like to read data arrived in the period between 8th mar 2023 to 14th mar 2023

Is there a way we can define ending position along with initialPosition in below.

`spark.readStream.format("kinesis").option("streamName", kinesisStreamName).option("region", kinesisRegion).option("initialPosition", '{"at_timestamp": "03/08/2023 00:00:00 PDT", "format": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"}').option("awsAccessKey", awsAccessKeyId).option("awsSecretKey", awsSecretKey).load()`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a Batch processing not a Stream processing, since you desire like a backfill job.

Unfortunately, you can't set like endPosition config to Spark Streaming app to read Kafka or Kinesis.

Some suggestions:

1- If you have a chance like changing Kinesis to Kafka then you can use spark.read("kafka") method instead spark.readStream("kafka"). So, you can use below parameters.

```py
    .option("startingOffsets", start_offset) \
    .option("endingOffsets", end_offset) \
```

2- If Kinesis usage is required, then you can feed a s3 path with your this Kinesis Stream. Then you can consume its data files with Spark by setting a start-end where condition. (I would recommend AWS-Glue pushdown_predicate feature not to read all data).

Thanks.